# Is there a way to group related files in Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Consider a situation with a typical .NET web solution.  For a give web page you have the view (.cshtml), page's .js file, page's .css file, controller class, View Model file, the business object, the stored proc, etc...

All these reside in different directories/projects in the solution.  So I spent a good portion of time hunting around for these.

Is there a construct in VS that allows me to group these together somewhere, so I don't have to go hunting for them?  E.g. some virtual folder that has these files in it.

```
Employee.cshtml, 
employee.js, 
employee.css, 
EmployeeController.cs, 
EmployeeViewModel.cs, 
EmployeeEntity.cs, 
get/upd/ins/delEmployee.sql, 
etc...
```

Comment: Maybe you don't know about the Ctrl-P search feature (I'm guessing maybe command-P on Mac).  Hit that and then type in "employee" and you'd find all of them in a drop-down list.

Answer (score 1):

You can group these files with my [Tabs Studio](https://tabsstudio.com/) extension, so that when one of these files is opened, right clicking on the opened tab title will show all corresponding files with the ability to quickly open them.

It will require to set up custom title and path grouping rules specific for your solution organization:
https://tabsstudio.com/documentation/visual_studio_tab_grouping.html